# React Native : No store found. Make sure to follow these instructions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, redux, react-redux

I don't understand :
I have a store and I've installed redux-devtools-extension to follow my tree store.

But devtool can't find my store in my react native app.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
));
```

Here my package version :

```
"react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.25",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
"react-redux": "^7.2.3",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

I don't understand where is the problem.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you wrapped your App in a react-redux Provider component? <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>

Comment: Yes ! I did it in my app. Adn the store work in my app. Just I can't see it on my debugger

Comment: Did you connect your component to the store ?

Comment: @docmurloc yes I did it. I use my store in my component. But what do you mean more with "connect your component to the store" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to export your store. Try below steps

*Step 1:* Create store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import profile from '../reducers/profile';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: profile
});

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );
};

export default configureStore;
```

*Step 2:* Connect your store in `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

*Step 3:* Connect store inside your component like below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.profile)
    return (
      <div className="row">
      <div> Welcome to React-Redux
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    profile: state.user.profile
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

[Complete Source Code with React-Redux and DEMO](https://github.com/Jebasuthan/React-form-registration)